# How can I calculate the amount of days within a date range that fall within another specific date range in Excel 2010.

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In Excel 2010, I need to determine the amount of days within a date range that fall within another specific date range.

An example of this is that our client has utilized our services from 03/08/2015 to 04/08/2015 but our billing cycle is from 04/01/2015-04/30/2015. That being said, we are required to bill the client for the service days within the billing cycle.

What is an Excel or Google Sheets formula to determine the amount of service days between the billing cycle dates.

Service Start Date 
3/8/15
Service End Date
4/8/15

Billing Cycle Start Date
4/1/15
Billing Cycle End Date
4/30/15

Expected Result 
8

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please do some research and try to accomplish this yourself. People here are happy reviewing code / formulas but not writing it for you completely. And also, this question [has been asked before](https://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow+excel+days+between+dates). If you fail, edit your question to include what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example

In Column A
Actual Billed Time Range
A2 Start of Billing
A3 End of Billing

In Column B
Billing Cycle
B2 Start of Billing Period
B3 End of Billing Period

In Column C
Formulas
Place the following in C2

```
=IF(B2>A2,B2,A2)
```

This checks the start date of Actual Time Billed vs the Monthly Billing Start and if the Actual Time Billed date is less then it will start with the Monthly Billing Start Date

Place the following in C3

```
=IF(B3<A3,B3,A3)
```

This checks the end date of Actual Time Billed vs the Monthly Billing end date and if the Actual Time Billed date is greater then it will end with the Monthly Billing end date.

To get your result place the following in D2 (format this cell as general and not date to get the proper result)

```
=C3-C2+1
```

or for a simpler looking sheet enter the following into C2 instead (format this cell as general and not date to get the proper result)

```
=(IF(B3<A3,B3,A3))-(IF(B2>A2,B2,A2))+1
```

It just combines the cells in Column C and D into one cell for a nicer look I unfortunately can not post images to show it working as i am fairly new here.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Service Start Date in A3 and Service End Date in B3 then put the Billing Cycle start and end dates in C1 and C2 respectively, then you can use this formula in C3 for the number of days in that Billing Cycle

> =MAX(0,MIN(C$2,$B3)-MAX(C$1,$A3)+1)

You may have to adjust the formula depending on whether you are including start or end dates in the calculation (how many days do you expect in the previous billing cycle for your example?)

This formula can be copied across and down as required, so you can have service periods which go across many billing periods, just add the additional dates in rows 1 and 2..... or you can also add multiple service periods in columns A and B